# Bind label in templatefield from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview set in the aspx file having a label in the itemtemplate tag:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Field" SortExpression="Field">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Font-Size="12px" ID="lblField" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DataTableField","{0:N0}") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <asp:Label Font-Size="12px" ID="FieldTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" />
                    </div>
                </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Instead of creating the templatefield in the aspx file, i am trying to create them dynamically from the codebehind cs file.

What I have so far is this:

```
foreach (DataColumn DC in myDataTable.Columns)
        {
            TemplateField TF = new TemplateField();
            Label myLabel = new Label();
            myLabel.Text = bindFromCS();
            TF.HeaderText = DC.ColumnName;
            TF.SortExpression = DC.ColumnName;
            TF.ItemTemplate = new CreateItemTemplate(myLabel);
            GridView1.Columns.Add(TF);
        }
```

What I'm failing to do is create the bindFromCS() method so that it replaces the bind method in the aspx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways that you can make this dynamic.

One way is that you have to use RowDataBound event of the gridview to manually assign values to the control. In your AgentSum_RowDataBound function you can do the following to assign value to the label dynamically

```
        protected void AgentSum_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
                        var dataItem = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow; //change this to your domain object type
        foreach (Control RowControl in e.Row.Controls)
        {
            if (RowControl as Label != null) (RowControl as Label).Text = dataItem[(RowControl as Label).Text].ToString();
        }
        }
```

Second approach is you can create a function in the code behind
        protected string GetSumDateValue(DateTime sumDate)
        {
            return sumDate.ToString(); // Change your logic here
        }

and call this function in your aspx as below

```
Text='<%# GetSumDateValue(Eval("SumDate")) %>'>
```

Thrid approach is add a function to the domain object iteself

```
public string FormattedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return SumDate.ToString(); // Change your logic here
        }
    }
```

Bind the formatted date to your label

```
 <asp:Label Font-Size="12px" ID="lblSumDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FormattedDate") %>'></asp:Label>
```

You can use whichever approach that suits you

Comment: I'm using the first way and have another question:
If the dataitemtype is DataRow (from a DataTable),
how do I get the relevant column dynamically?
(I'm refering to the code line where I "assign dynamically any value here")

Comment: Which type of list are you binding to the gridview? I mean what is the type of datasource items? You can cast the e.Row.DataItem to this type. Then you can access any column

Comment: The datasource is a DataTable.
I can't find the correct syntax to refer to the relevant column in the DataRow?

Comment: If you are binding DataTable, then try to cast DataRow dataRow = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow; Then you can access the column using dataRow["SumDate"] for example.